# LDAP over TLS using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, security, ssl

I am trying to implement LDAP over TLS and I am getting the following exception:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
simple bind failed: greater.com.au:636; nested exception is 
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: greater.com.au:636 
[Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
valid certification path to requested target]
```

I understand that this is related to the server certificate's CA not being imported into my Java trust store. It is actually imported into my trust store and I am referencing the trust store using the properties:

```
server.ssl.trust-store=C:\truststore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=changeit
```

My security configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@Order(99)
@ConfigurationProperties("ad")
public class ActiveDirectorySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Setter
private String domain;
@Setter
private String url;
@Setter
@Value("${ad.authorities.allowed}")
private String authorities;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority(authorities)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()).userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(domain, url);
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

    return provider;
}
}
```

Through extensive debugging it appears that the SSLContext may not be loading my trust store correctly. So my question would be where I can hook into the SSL context using the configuration setup I've got so that the TLS connection is created successfully?

Comment: Try it with `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\truststore.jks` if you can.

Comment: I have tried it with that. I'm fairly sure server.ssl.trustStore is the Spring Boot equivalent.

Comment: Also server.ssl.trustStore is interchangeable with server.ssl.trust-store.